# What is the correct way of saving values into a constant in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user model and I have used timestamps in it. I need to access the `createdAt` date and save it in a variable. I tried

```
const date = await User.find({
      serial: serialId,
    }).select('-_id createdAt');
```

But this is returning

```
[ { createdAt: 2021-09-23T10:47:24.400Z } ]
```

However the only thing that i want to be saved inside my date constant is

```
2021-09-23T10:47:24.400Z
```

that also as a Date()

Comment: Did you try destructuring the response? `const [{ createdAt: date }] = await User.find(...)` - also, `findOne` sounds better suited, then you can drop the `[ ]` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use findOne, it returns one document. documentation of findOne : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne

```
const date = await User.findOne({
          serial: serialId,
        }, '-_id createdAt').exec();
    
    console.log(date.createdAt)
```

or

```
const {createdAt :  date}= await User.findOne({
          serial: serialId,
        }, '-_id createdAt').exec();
    
    console.log(date)
```

```js
const {createdAt :  date} = { createdAt: '2021-09-23T10:47:24.400Z' }
console.log(date)
let fromDate = new Date(date);
console.log(fromDate.getDate())
```

Also look here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/#return-date-as-date-object

Comment: This method is working perfectly for the first half of the question. But date methods such as getDate() getDay() are not working with it

Comment: @durayfishan i have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an array because `find()` returns all matches.
Get the property from the first object. Use it with the `Date()` constructor to get your required value as date.

Try this:

```
const date = await User.find({
      serial: serialId,
    }).select('-_id createdAt');

let finalDate = new Date(date[0].createdAt);
console.log(finalDate);
```

Comment: console.log(finalDate) is printing Invalid date

Comment: Sorry. I did not see one detail.Please check now